# vim copy to buffer gdb breakpoint command string

Tags: vim, gdb

I need to copy in buffer line of below form by pressing sequence \br in vim command mode

```
br /absolute_path/current_file : cursor_line
```

I think it should be similar to this:

```
:noremap <silent> \fn :let @*=expand('%:p')<CR>:echo "filename copied: ".@*<CR>
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure I fully understand you question but looks like you're very close. If all you want is to copy the current filename you should write it like this:

```
:noremap <silent> \fn :execute "let @*='".expand('%:p')."'"<cr>:echo "filename copied: ".@*<cr>
```

if what you want is filename:currentLineNumber then you should write this instead

```
:noremap <silent> \fn :execute "let @*='".expand('%:p').":".getpos('.')[1]."'"<cr>:echo "filename copied: ".@*<cr>
```

if what you want is filename:contentsOfCurrentCursorLine then use this instead

```
:noremap <silent> \fn :execute "let @*='".expand('%:p').":".getline('.')."'"<cr>:echo "filename copied: ".@*<cr>
```

Comment: :noremap <silent> \br :execute "let @*='br ".expand('%:p').":".getpos('.')[1]."'"<CR>:echo "breakpoint: ".@*<CR>

Comment: I just wanted to have breakpoint on current string, we're planning to integrate gdb into vim, but strugled to do it in the past, so I decided to have this convinient generation. Thanks.

Comment: just learned that you may use `line('.')` instead of `getpos('.')[1]`. It's a bit cleaner!

Comment: If you want this directly to copy break point string to your clipboard which then can be pasted straight to gdb. I modified it a bit to directly place b and copy to + register. https://github.com/Kazhuu/dotfiles/blob/master/vim/ftplugin/c.vim#L10